# XSL for each - get single value from nodes

Tags: xml, xslt

Hi all I have an xml file containing the following section:

```
<sml:inputs>
<sml:InputList>
      <sml:input name="instrument_A">
          <sml:ObservableProperty definition="instrument_A"/>
      </sml:input>
      <sml:input name="instrument_B">
          <sml:ObservableProperty definition="instrument_B"/>
      </sml:input>
      <sml:input name="instrument_C">
          <sml:ObservableProperty definition="instrument_C"/>
      </sml:input>
      <sml:input name="instrument_D">
          <sml:ObservableProperty definition="instrument_D"/>
      </sml:input>              
</sml:InputList>
```

What I would like to do is to write an `XSL` file which gives me the following output:

```
 <gmd:keyword>
     <gco:CharacterString>instrument_A</gco:CharacterString>
 </gmd:keyword>
 <gmd:keyword>
     <gco:CharacterString>instrument_B</gco:CharacterString>
 </gmd:keyword>
 <gmd:keyword>
    <gco:CharacterString>instrument_C</gco:CharacterString>
 </gmd:keyword>
 <gmd:keyword>
     <gco:CharacterString>instrument_D</gco:CharacterString>
 </gmd:keyword>
```

I tried with this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/sml:inputs/sml:InputList/sml:input">
    <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
```

But I got the following wrong result:

```
<gmd:keyword>instrument_Ainstrument_Binstrument_Cinstrument_D</gmd:keyword>
```

Could you please tell me how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't shown your existing code where you create the `gmd:keyword` element, but I am guessing you are doing it outside the `xsl:for-each`, so that it only gets created once, and contains all your text as one.

You simply need to move it inside the `xsl:for-each`.

As a starter, try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" 
        xmlns:sml="sml" xmlns:gmd="gmd" xmlns:gco="gco"
        exclude-result-prefixes="sml">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <gmd:ouptput>
            <xsl:for-each select="/sml:inputs/sml:InputList/sml:input">
                <gmd:keyword>
                    <gco:CharacterString>
                        <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
                    </gco:CharacterString>
                </gmd:keyword>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </gmd:ouptput>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note you will have to update the namespace declarations to match your actually requirements, as you have not shown this in your question.